# C++ Builder XE - customizing TCategoryPanel

Tags: components, customization, c++builder, c++builder-xe

This is part of screenshot of my application:

[image]

I need to do following things:

1. remove lines separating collapsed panels
2. remove line on bottom border of expanded panel

The lines I am talking about are highlighted by character '!' in image.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished the second task by creating formal descendent class of *TCategoryPanel*:

```
class MyCategoryPanel : public TCategoryPanel
{
public:
    __property BevelWidth;
};
```

The goal is to change visibility of *BevelWidth* property from protected to public. Now we can set bevel width to zero for example like this (code is called from parent form class):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ComponentCount; i++) {
    TComponent *component = Components[i];
    TCategoryPanel *cat_panel = dynamic_cast<TCategoryPanel*>(component);
    if (cat_panel == NULL) {
        continue;
    }
    ((MyCategoryPanel*)cat_panel)->BevelWidth = 0;
}
```